# How to deploy bitbucket framework to Sandbox?

Tags: ant, framework

How to deploy bitbucket framework to Sandbox?
I cloned my bitbucket branch and I have a copy on my desktop.
How do I get the javascript framework I copied to Salesforce sandbox?
I read the documentation, it state that to install java and ANT, which I did. 
What now? 
Can someone please explain this to me step by step, I have been googling for hours and have not found anything that works.
thank you kindly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're throwing together a bunch of concepts here that need to be assembled in order to form a coherent development process.

#### BitBucket

... is a hosting provider for Git (and Mercurial) version control repositories. Git repositories hosted on BitBucket can hold Salesforce source code (or any source code), that may represent the contents of one of your orgs, whether production or sandbox, and which can be deployed to other orgs.

#### The Force.com Migration Tool

... which is built on Java and Ant, is one of many tools that can be used to deploy Salesforce metadata to an org, or extract it from an org, into the textual format that is stored in a version control system.

Like all Metadata API-based tools, the Force.com Migration Tool uses a `package.xml` file as a manifest of the metadata components to be manipulated.

Note that for day-to-day development, you'll likely want to be using an IDE, Salesforce DX, or the Force.com CLI to push and pull metadata to and from your sandbox. It's somewhat more common for the Migration Tool to be used in headless, continuous integration workflows.

#### JavaScript Frameworks

... can be used in Visualforce or in some cases in Lightning components, and are typically stored as static resources. Static resources are one of the metadata items that can be versioned through Git and BitBucket and deployed using the Force.com Migration Tool.

#### But Also

You don't need to use all this tooling just to put a JavaScript framework in your Salesforce instance. You're free to upload Static Resources directly into your sandbox without using a tool chain, which might be eminently appropriate if you're just getting started with a development process.

You may want to consider adopting an IDE, such as the Eclipse-based Force.com IDE, MavensMate + editor, Visual Studio Code with Salesforce DX, Illuminated Cloud, etc. There's lots of resources available online and on StackExchange for all of these tools.

Comment: you complete me <3